# How to remove an item from gem PATH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, rubygems

I was trying to update Rails and I ran `gem install rails` from my home directory and I now have a .gem directory in my home dir.

I eventually was able to update Rails properly, and deleted the .gem folder, but I now have this extra PATH in my GEM PATHS that I wanted to get rid of:

```
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/homedir/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/
```

How do I remove this? What is the "proper" way to remove this line? I haven't the foggiest idea. Running OS X 10.6.4, Ruby 1.8.7, Gem 1.3.7, and Rails 3.0.0.

I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Can not, for the life of me, figure this out. Where the hell is the ORIGINAL GEM PATH information stored? It must be somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “original gem path information” is set in rubygems source themselves.

I also wanted to do it, and haven’t found a way… Then I looked for in rubygems source (at github.com) and learned that it tries to get the path from etc/gemrc and ~/.gemrc. If it fails (and fails GEM_PATH environment variable too), it assumes ~/.gem… to be the default path.

Therefore, you have either to export GEM_PATH or to create a ~/.gemrc.

Hope to have cleared things a bit!

Comment: Wow. I wish I could give you a million upvotes for this. It irked me to no end, but this is what I suspected. Thanks for actually taking the time to look. I'm sure we aren't the only ones who wondered what was up with this. :)